# Find time spent in each state using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, stacked-chart

calculate time spent in each state
i have a data as given below:

| Ticket num | Created | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ticket_1 | 11/3/2022 0:06 | P4 |
| Ticket_1 | 11/3/2022 0:18 | P4 |
| Ticket_1 | 11/3/2022 0:21 | P3 |
| Ticket_1 | 11/3/2022 0:22 | P2 |
| Ticket_1 | 11/3/2022 0:23 | P1 |
| Ticket_1 | 11/3/2022 0:24 | P1 |
| Ticket_1 | 11/3/2022 0:26 | P1 |
| Ticket_2 | 12/12/2022 13:40 | P1 |
| Ticket_2 | 12/12/2022 13:41 | P1 |
| Ticket_2 | 12/12/2022 13:43 | P2 |
| Ticket_2 | 12/12/2022 13:45 | P2 |
| Ticket_2 | 12/12/2022 13:45 | P4 |
| Ticket_2 | 12/12/2022 13:46 | P3 |
| Ticket_2 | 12/13/2022 14:00 | P1 |

i would now like to calculate time spent by each state in hours/seconds for every ticket  in a 100% stacked bar chart and see the transition for  state for Ticket_1 which changes from P4-->P3-->P2-->P1

Final chart to look something like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a Calculated Column with:

```
Duration = 
  var thisTime = [Created]
  var toTime = CALCULATE(MIN([Created]), ALLEXCEPT('Ticket', 'Ticket'[Ticket num]), 'Ticket'[Created] > thisTime)
  return DATEDIFF(thisTime, toTime, MINUTE)
```

To give you:
[image]

**Note**

- Assuming the first (min) date is the start.
- Your table needs a `Closed` datetime column otherwise the last row for each ticket won't be included.

**Additional**
To get the chart to show the order of state, then the best that can be achieved with native visuals is like shown below. However, unable to have the each Px color match.
[image]

Create two more calculated columns with the following (in order):

```
state_change = 
  var thisCreated = [Created]
  var thisTicket = [Ticket num]
  var prevFilter = TOPN(1, FILTER(Ticket, Ticket[Ticket num] = thisTicket && Ticket[Created] < thisCreated), [Created], DESC)
  var prevValue = CALCULATE(MIN('Ticket'[state]), prevFilter)
  return IF(prevValue <> [state], [state])


state_index = 
  var thisTime = [Created]
  var stateCount = CALCULATE(COUNT(Ticket[state_change]), ALLEXCEPT('Ticket', 'Ticket'[Ticket num]), 'Ticket'[Created] <= thisTime)
  return stateCount
```

Then for the chart:

- **Y-axis** - `Ticket num`
- **X-axis** - `Duration`
- **Legend** - `state_index`
- **Tooltip** - `state`
- Properties

  - Switch off the legend (optional)
  - `Data labels` `On`.
    Data labels > Values > `Custom label` `On` and add `state` to the field.
    `Overflow text` `On`.

Comment: Duration = 
  var thisTime = [Created]
  var toTime = CALCULATE(MIN([Created]), ALLEXCEPT('Ticket', 'Ticket'[Ticket num]), 'Ticket'[Created] > thisTime)
  return COALESCE(DATEDIFF(thisTime, toTime, MINUTE),0)-->coalesce would work to add zero to the last row... @SamNseir ....but what i want is the state to be in the exact order in the chart--> like for ticket_1 state changes rom P4-->P3-->P3-->P1 & for ticket_2 state changes from P1-->P2-->P4-->P3-->P1

Comment: Best you can achieve with the inbuilt visuals is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZYj5.png - this shows what you are after however cannot change the colours to be the same per state.

Comment: Added the additional info to the answer above.

Comment: Please Accept answer for the benefit of all.